# Using SSH ProxyJump with Coda

Tags: ssh, panic, coda

I am away from home, and need to proxy jump via my home server to connect to a number of sites.

The settings in .ssh/config work 100% of the time every time when executing from the command line, but coda simply refuses to use these connections.

```
Host home
  Hostname my.home.server
  Port 222
  ProxyCommand bash -c '/usr/local/bin/knock -v %h $KNOCKS; sleep 1; exec /usr/bin/nc %h %p'

Host host1
  Hostname host1.com
  User root

Host home-host1
  Hostname host1.com
  User root

Host home-*
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p home
```

So If I want to connect via home I:

ssh home-host1 and it jumps through my home to host1

Now this works all the time, every time for ssh via the console, but coda simply wont connect.

In the coda setup I have added home-host1 as the server and tried setting and clearing the user name and port so that just like ssh in a terminal everything comes from the config file.

I have also cleared known_hosts just in case it was caching something from there but no-go.

What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, after a lot more trial and error I succeeded.

coda does not appear to like ProxyJump but it will work with ProxyCommand

```
Host home-*
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p home
```

Comment: You might like to use `ProxyJump` instead; all you need to specify is the host: `ProxyJump home`.

Comment: Thanks, panic have already confirmed that ProxyJump will not work with coda.